# decision on if the data size if good for regression analysis

Tags: regression

I have a country-vise and year-vise species richness data The column name for species richness is Species, which is a count data. I want to do a country-vise analysis for each year. There are very few rows in the data having a value in the Species column > 10. I am not clear if I should do regression analysis on this data or I should remove the rows with a value in the Species column < 10. I am attaching my data herewith. I use R software for the analysis.[image]

Comment: Why do you think you should remove data it the outcome is smaller than 10?

Comment: @Demetri Pananos, I thought small data size would result in inaccurate estimate. Hence I felt data lesser than a certain value should be removed. But I am not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: no it is not the correct approach.  By removing data, you would be biasing estimates.  Do not do this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Demetri Pananos.